# Parentheses not showing in axis labels in r with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to create a graph with parentheses in the x-axis label, but the parentheses and any text between them are not showing up.

Here's the code:

```
ggplot(newData, aes(Size, Seconds)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(fill = Method), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
   scale_x_discrete("Size") + 
   ggtitle("Cached Comparison (lower is better)") + 
   xlab("Size (MB)")
```

[This is the graph that is being produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsKO.png)

I have tried saving the label as a variable using this code:

```
label <- "Size (MB)"
```

Then altering the graph to use:

```
xlab(label)
```

But the output is the same. How can I get the parentheses to show in the label?

Comment: I have not, but it appears the scale_x_discrete() call is overriding the labeling. Changing that value to "Size (MB)" seems to be fixing the issue. Although I cannot explain why.

Comment: why would  you have scale_x_discrete("Size")  and then xlab("Size (MB)")? couldn't you keep just one?

Comment: And, as the `Details` section of `?xlab` says: *"You can also set axis and legend labels in the individual scales (using the first argument, the `name`. I recommend doing that if you're changing other scale options."*. It doesn't specifically say `xlab` has lower precedence, but I would follow the advice of the documentation and use only the `scale_x_discrete`, remove the `xlab()` entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to manually enter the elements on x and label x with xlab.

```
ggplot(newData, aes(Size, Seconds)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Time), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1","10","100","1000", "5000")) + 
  ggtitle("Cached Comparison (lower is better)") + 
  xlab("Size (MB)")
```